# all possible jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this problem in my linear algebra course and I have never seen this type. Let $T : \mathbb{Q}^3 → \mathbb{Q}^3 $ a linear application s.t $(T^7 + 2I)(T^2 + 3T + 2I)^2 = 0$ Find all possible Jordan forms and the relative characteristic polinomial.

my attempt : I have tried to find the zeroes of teh application T  and they are $-2^{1/7}$ with algebraic multeplicity =1 and $-2 , -1 $ with algebraic multiplicity =2. This means that I  have 3 jordan blocks . This means that all possible matrix are  permutation of these 3 blocks?

Comment: However, note that the minimal polynomial also divides the characteristic polynomial, which is a degree-$3$ polynomial with rational coefficients. Does that rule out some of the possible eigenvalues? (Be careful also not to conclude that all roots of the given polynomial are eigenvalues—the eigenvalues are a subset of those roots. Also don't forget complex roots of the polynomial.)

Answer (score 1):

We need that the minimal polynomial $m_T$ *divides* the given polynomial.

Now, $x^7+2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, so it won't give a factor of degree $\le 3$.

The other possible factors are $(x+1)$ and $(x+2)$, both with multiplicity at most $2$.

So, the possible minimal polynomials are $(x+1)^a(x+2)^b$ with any $0\le a\le 2,\ 0\le b\le 2,\ 1\le a+b\le 3$.

Comment: thanks for you answer . This means now that I have only eigenvalues -1,-2  but what abut all possible characteristic polynomial ?

Comment: I thought you can carry on from here. E g. what are the possible characteristic polynomials for minimal polynomial $(x+1)(x+2)$ and what are the corresponding Jordan forms?